# eddystone beacon automatic disconnect after some time and not sending Major and minor

Tags: java, android

I am using nRF connect Apk for set Major and Minor. Always  beacon is disconnect and it stop sending Major and Minor.
I was try many apps but same condition arrives.
Please suggest me what i will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1:First check your beacon is ibeacon or not 
Step 2:If your beacon is not ibeacon than make it ibeacon first by using
nRFConnect app.
Step 3:By using nRFConnect app you make your beacon in ibeacon after making ibeacon you use following code to get Major,Minor and UUID of beacon

```
 List<ADStructure> structures = ADPayloadParser.getInstance().parse(scanRecord);

 for (ADStructure structure : structures) {
         String majorvalue= bytesToHex(structure.getData());
         if (structure instanceof IBeacon) {
                IBeacon iBeacon = (IBeacon) structure;
                UUID uuidvalue = iBeacon.getUUID();
                uuid=uuidvalue.toString();
                 major = String.valueOf(iBeacon.getMajor());
                 minor = String.valueOf(iBeacon.getMinor());
    }
}
```

https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-bluetooth